# Why is casting with dynamic faster than with object

Tags: c#, performance, object, dynamic, performance-testing

I am really confused, take the following code:

```cs
[Benchmark]
public TEnum DynamicCast()
{
    return (TEnum)(dynamic)0;
}

[Benchmark]
public TEnum ObjectCast()
{
    return (TEnum)(object)0;
}

[Benchmark]
public TEnum DirectCast()
{
    return (TEnum)0;
}

public enum TEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

And yes I know that I could directly cast the integer to the given Enum, but this is a simplified version of my actual code which includes the work with generic extensions.

Anyhow I ran a few performance tests, because I was curious which one is faster. I am using `BenchmarkDotNet` and see there:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU 2.60GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.56402, CoreFX 4.700.19.56404), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.56402, CoreFX 4.700.19.56404), X64 RyuJIT


|      Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |     Median |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------ |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| DynamicCast |  8.2124 ns | 0.0803 ns | 0.0671 ns |  8.2134 ns | 0.0076 |     - |     - |      24 B |
|  ObjectCast | 13.9178 ns | 0.4822 ns | 0.5922 ns | 13.6714 ns | 0.0076 |     - |     - |      24 B |
|  DirectCast |  0.0538 ns | 0.0422 ns | 0.0534 ns |  0.0311 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
```

The dynamic version is actually faster and not just by a bit. I ran the test multiple times and I can't wrap my head around it.

I looked at the compiled version, if there might be any optimization, but see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8BmAAiJoGEaBvCimju2gFQFEA7AK4BbGgBEAnvwCGwgJZgG0gM4AXABQBKdp1blOBugHYa6vkOGb1GKbIWaADAG4dHAL6uan6jXMiaAPLAAFYwYKpKalqeeoac+CZmAiJWECFhqo4u+pweORzetDAWvsnCMZ4GAGIQEGiVnABC0lCeeW5AA).

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: how about you also compare direct cast `return (TEnum)0;` and any differences ? i suspect the level of boxing/unboxing will impact the optmisation, something to do with implicit/explicit type conversion.

Comment: Gonna guess it has to do with boxing / unboxing vs. straight casting via dynamic

Comment: @Jonesopolis this would still surprise me, since from personal experience, working with dynamic always has some overhead. In this case I really think it is higher then the boxing overhead...

Comment: @Turbot updated the answer and yes the reason for it being so fast because it will compile to `TEnum.Foo`.

Comment: Also, note that Dynamic invocations are aggressively cached.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so the resulting cast is being cached and is therefor faster then the object cast?

Comment: I'm just speculating, I don't know if it applies here

Comment: @AluanHaddad well it would be _the only_ logical explanation.

Comment: I think we need more information

Comment: @Twenty object cast actually boxes and unboxes the value, dynamic cast uses runtime binding of cast method. I've added an answer with IL details, please have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at IL code to see the difference under the hood. Object cast

```cs
public TEnum ObjectCast()
{
    return (TEnum)(object)0;
}
```

box `int` value into `object` and then unbox into `TEnum` value, since it's value type

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
IL_0002: box          [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0007: unbox.any    TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum
IL_000c: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_000d: br.s         IL_000f
```

I guess that it's a main reason of the slowest execution in comparison with other samples.

The `dynamic` object cast

```cs
public TEnum DynamicCast()
{
    return (TEnum) (dynamic) 0;
}
```

looks more complicated

```
IL_0001: ldsfld       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>> TestConsoleApp.Test/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
IL_0006: brfalse.s    IL_000a
IL_0008: br.s         IL_002f
IL_000a: ldc.i4.s     16 // 0x10
IL_000c: ldtoken      TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum
IL_0011: call         class [System.Runtime]System.Type [System.Runtime]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_0016: ldtoken      TestConsoleApp.Test
IL_001b: call         class [System.Runtime]System.Type [System.Runtime]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_0020: call         class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::Convert(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags, class [System.Runtime]System.Type, class [System.Runtime]System.Type)
IL_0025: call         class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<!0/*class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>*/> class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>>::Create(class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)
IL_002a: stsfld       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>> TestConsoleApp.Test/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
IL_002f: ldsfld       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>> TestConsoleApp.Test/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
IL_0034: ldfld        !0/*class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>*/ class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>>::Target
IL_0039: ldsfld       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>> TestConsoleApp.Test/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
IL_003e: ldc.i4.0
IL_003f: box          [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0044: callvirt     instance !2/*valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum*/ class [System.Runtime]System.Func`3<class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, valuetype TestConsoleApp.Test/TEnum>::Invoke(!0/*class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite*/, !1/*object*/)
IL_0049: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_004a: br.s         IL_004c
```

There is a type information loaded, then instance of `CallSiteBinder` is initialized using `Binder.Convert` [static method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder.convert?view=netframework-4.8) Then an instance of generic `CallSite` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callsite-1?view=netcore-3.1) is created, using `Create` [static call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callsite-1.create?view=netcore-3.1) (`ldsfld` pushes the value of static field into the stack). I'm not 100% sure, but the generic argument `Func<CallSite, object, TEnum` means a function, which will be invoked to convert the object into `TEnum`. Last lines show that this function is bound to `TEnum` class.

So, under the hood compiler already creates you a method to cast a dynamic object to required `TEnum` type. And there is only boxing operation from `int` to `object` to pass it to created function. This sounds like a good reason, why it's faster than object cast with boxing and unboxing operations

Comment: Seems like unboxing overhead is greater than DLR Callsite caching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the deeper dive. This also seems to be the most logical answer.

Comment: The jit should be able to optimize the box/unbox.any pattern and give similar perf as in a direct cast, but this fails if one of the types is an enum and the other is an int.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the implicit/explicit type conversion has impact to your operation.
the `DirectCast` are the fastest among to explicit cast - `ObjectCast` and `DynamicCast` is implementing implicit cast that's generally into your result.

Comment: So therefor it is always faster when talking about casting (ignoring the direct cast for a second) and not just restricted to Enums? Also the compiler generated code is much longer and also seems more complex for the `DynamicCast`. Even shouldn't it be at least just a few lines more? I imagine a implicit cast to be easier then an explicit.